# NonLinearModelFit with enormous integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fitting, nonlinear

I have defined the following function in Mathematica:

$\int_0^t[\int_0^a e^{-\frac{r^2+r'^2}{4Diff(t-t')}}I_o (\frac{rr'}{2Diff(t-t')})r'^2 dr']\times \frac{e^{-\alpha z + \alpha^2 Diff(t-t')}}{Diff(t-t')} Erfc(\frac{2Diff \alpha(t-t')-z}{\sqrt{4Diff(t-t')}})dt'$

`TempDist[r_, z_, t_, a_, Diff_, \[Alpha]_] := NIntegrate[(ro^2) Exp[-(ro^2 + r^2)/(4 Diff (t - ti))] BesselI[0, ro r/(2 Diff (t - ti))] Exp[-\[Alpha]*z + (\[Alpha]^2)*Diff (t - ti)]*Erfc[(2 Diff \[Alpha] (t - ti) - z)/(Sqrt[4 Diff (t - ti)])]/(Diff (t - ti)), {ro, 0, a}, {ti, 0, t}, PrecisionGoal -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 10];`

I am trying to fit a dataset to this function (1000 points). The independent variables are $r$ and $t$. The values of $z$ and $\alpha$ are already known, so the only parameters I'm trying to get are $a$ and $Diff$.

The problem is that when I ask Mathematica to fit:

`nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 4.15*TempDist[r, 2, t, a, Diff, 0.023], {{Diff, 0.125}, {a, 4.0}}, {r, t}]`

The following messages appear:

`NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option. >>`

`General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::izero will be suppressed during this calculation. >>`

And the calculation never finishes. Am I missing something on the way the integral is being computed?

Here is the dataset I am trying to fit:

`{{0,0,0.788942},{0,6,0.},{0,12,0.},{0,18,0.788942},{0,24,1.05192},{0,30,1.05192},{0,36,0.920433},{0,42,2.62981},{0,48,2.10385},{0,54,2.36683},{0,60,1.70937},{0,66,3.55024},{0,72,2.89279},{0,78,2.89279},{0,84,3.28726},{0,90,3.68173},{0,96,3.15577},{0,102,3.28726},{0,108,3.41875},{0,114,2.89279},{0,120,2.49832},{0,126,3.41875},{0,132,3.15577},{0,138,2.89279},{0,144,3.41875},{0,150,3.02428},{0,156,3.41875},{0,162,3.94471},{0,168,3.02428},{0,174,3.15577},{0,180,3.81322},{0,186,3.68173},{0,192,3.81322},{0,198,3.02428},{0,204,3.41875},{0,210,3.15577},{0,216,3.28726},{0,222,3.68173},{0,228,3.55024},{0,234,4.20769},{0,240,3.15577},{0,246,4.20769},{0,252,3.94471},{0,258,4.0762},{0,264,4.60216},{0,270,3.28726},{0,276,3.94471},{0,282,3.94471},{0,288,4.33918},{0,294,3.68173},{0,300,3.41875},{0,306,3.81322},{0,312,4.73365},{0,318,3.41875},{0,324,3.41875},{0,330,3.81322},{0,336,4.47067},{0,342,4.20769},{0,348,3.68173},{0,354,3.94471},{0,360,3.81322},{0,366,4.73365},{0,372,4.33918},{0,378,4.99663},{0,384,4.60216},{0,390,4.73365},{0,396,4.33918},{0,402,4.47067},{0,408,4.0762},{0,414,5.25962},{0,420,4.20769},{0,426,3.28726},{0,432,4.86514},{0,438,4.60216},{0,444,4.33918},{0,450,4.33918},{0,456,3.94471},{0,462,3.94471},{0,468,4.20769},{0,474,3.68173},{0,480,4.86514},{0,486,3.28726},{0,492,5.12813},{0,498,4.0762},{0,504,5.78558},{0,510,5.65409},{0,516,4.47067},{0,522,5.12813},{0,528,5.5226},{0,534,4.60216},{0,540,4.33918},{0,546,4.73365},{0,552,5.12813},{0,558,5.12813},{0,564,4.73365},{0,570,4.60216},{0,576,4.20769},{0,582,4.33918},{0,588,4.60216},{0,594,4.0762},{0,600,4.73365},{0,606,6.18005},{0,612,5.25962},{0,618,4.73365},{0,624,5.39111},{0,630,4.73365},{0,636,5.25962},{0,642,4.33918},{0,648,5.39111},{0,654,4.47067},{0,660,3.68173},{0,666,3.94471},{2,0,1.16512},{2,6,0.404215},{2,12,0.020846},{2,18,0.824866},{2,24,1.14326},{2,30,1.48389},{2,36,1.25155},{2,42,2.55875},{2,48,1.82298},{2,54,2.03449},{2,60,1.3055},{2,66,2.92561},{2,72,2.79616},{2,78,2.98746},{2,84,3.009},{2,90,3.63993},{2,96,3.47814},{2,102,3.22542},{2,108,3.74531},{2,114,3.56434},{2,120,2.98114},{2,126,3.84612},{2,132,3.73338},{2,138,3.7685},{2,144,3.78359},{2,150,3.49877},{2,156,3.59027},{2,162,3.81559},{2,168,3.89999},{2,174,3.62181},{2,180,3.73346},{2,186,3.93535},{2,192,3.82107},{2,198,3.62158},{2,204,3.65875},{2,210,3.88814},{2,216,3.61604},{2,222,4.00039},{2,228,4.12578},{2,234,4.2247},{2,240,3.53187},{2,246,4.31957},{2,252,4.19584},{2,258,4.49837},{2,264,4.33971},{2,270,4.36204},{2,276,3.96769},{2,282,4.4017},{2,288,4.58119},{2,294,4.18808},{2,300,4.15935},{2,306,4.10752},{2,312,4.76225},{2,318,4.11924},{2,324,4.01998},{2,330,4.05084},{2,336,4.53771},{2,342,4.71143},{2,348,4.36024},{2,354,3.88906},{2,360,3.93614},{2,366,4.64211},{2,372,4.35517},{2,378,4.84314},{2,384,4.86164},{2,390,4.69317},{2,396,4.47494},{2,402,4.52927},{2,408,4.50602},{2,414,5.1862},{2,420,4.48845},{2,426,4.11992},{2,432,4.87873},{2,438,4.41536},{2,444,4.33737},{2,450,4.38906},{2,456,4.34917},{2,462,4.20792},{2,468,4.69261},{2,474,4.02874},{2,480,5.06588},{2,486,4.14234},{2,492,5.32931},{2,498,4.41691},{2,504,5.69617},{2,510,5.58655},{2,516,4.54162},{2,522,4.52879},{2,528,4.99459},{2,534,4.61873},{2,540,4.32658},{2,546,4.94736},{2,552,4.49702},{2,558,4.5138},{2,564,4.30028},{2,570,4.03123},{2,576,4.11642},{2,582,3.96611},{2,588,4.40981},{2,594,4.07012},{2,600,4.47845},{2,606,5.30463},{2,612,5.37677},{2,618,4.50874},{2,624,5.18174},{2,630,5.29879},{2,636,4.49508},{2,642,4.34152},{2,648,5.21204},{2,654,4.17029},{2,660,4.52553},{2,666,4.87164},{4,0,0.549135},{4,6,0.},{4,12,0.},{4,18,0.339802},{4,24,0.416546},{4,30,0.511533},{4,36,0.507435},{4,42,1.71517},{4,48,1.32578},{4,54,1.36941},{4,60,0.831852},{4,66,2.01597},{4,72,1.59388},{4,78,1.66633},{4,84,1.95171},{4,90,2.26955},{4,96,1.98952},{4,102,2.20216},{4,108,2.45161},{4,114,2.02402},{4,120,1.44727},{4,126,2.45963},{4,132,1.97976},{4,138,2.40216},{4,144,2.29553},{4,150,1.84934},{4,156,1.97598},{4,162,2.40894},{4,168,2.16071},{4,174,2.12593},{4,180,2.21221},{4,186,2.19838},{4,192,2.00368},{4,198,2.30499},{4,204,2.22338},{4,210,2.03393},{4,216,1.90005},{4,222,2.30767},{4,228,2.35241},{4,234,2.58658},{4,240,2.04671},{4,246,2.57541},{4,252,3.12554},{4,258,2.9447},{4,264,3.14002},{4,270,2.55241},{4,276,2.96393},{4,282,2.66818},{4,288,2.83905},{4,294,2.67855},{4,300,2.59335},{4,306,2.50766},{4,312,3.00962},{4,318,2.77949},{4,324,2.45352},{4,330,2.13979},{4,336,2.98304},{4,342,2.92944},{4,348,2.6658},{4,354,2.63274},{4,360,2.3105},{4,366,3.02869},{4,372,2.96175},{4,378,3.1147},{4,384,3.00837},{4,390,2.59277},{4,396,2.81954},{4,402,2.74473},{4,408,2.86459},{4,414,3.77413},{4,420,3.01357},{4,426,2.59038},{4,432,3.49491},{4,438,2.94494},{4,444,2.93704},{4,450,2.93437},{4,456,3.00539},{4,462,2.72976},{4,468,3.18475},{4,474,2.7241},{4,480,3.15029},{4,486,2.52815},{4,492,3.52055},{4,498,2.70347},{4,504,4.0036},{4,510,3.72909},{4,516,3.14209},{4,522,2.97925},{4,528,3.20306},{4,534,2.94306},{4,540,2.75863},{4,546,3.16478},{4,552,3.10525},{4,558,2.96339},{4,564,2.8054},{4,570,2.6101},{4,576,2.48377},{4,582,2.34236},{4,588,2.98774},{4,594,2.40894},{4,600,2.76505},{4,606,3.71554},{4,612,3.62671},{4,618,3.04395},{4,624,3.5903},{4,630,3.27014},{4,636,3.15057},{4,642,2.67107},{4,648,3.2207},{4,654,2.63072},{4,660,2.78677},{4,666,2.92504},{6,0,1.21744},{6,6,0.374256},{6,12,0.167872},{6,18,0.603895},{6,24,1.10018},{6,30,1.08806},{6,36,1.0809},{6,42,1.90261},{6,48,1.56218},{6,54,1.53414},{6,60,1.0403},{6,66,1.90379},{6,72,1.84383},{6,78,1.76297},{6,84,1.81313},{6,90,2.17598},{6,96,2.09796},{6,102,2.041},{6,108,2.26989},{6,114,2.09157},{6,120,1.70227},{6,126,2.30022},{6,132,2.20457},{6,138,2.19272},{6,144,2.19187},{6,150,1.90349},{6,156,2.19106},{6,162,2.13228},{6,168,1.97139},{6,174,2.11059},{6,180,2.13849},{6,186,2.29438},{6,192,1.97575},{6,198,2.24628},{6,204,2.30613},{6,210,2.04594},{6,216,1.98422},{6,222,2.39187},{6,228,2.32553},{6,234,2.52546},{6,240,2.16609},{6,246,2.56854},{6,252,2.55461},{6,258,2.65491},{6,264,2.56333},{6,270,2.40599},{6,276,2.33022},{6,282,2.27972},{6,288,2.73393},{6,294,2.42457},{6,300,2.374},{6,306,2.46517},{6,312,2.67852},{6,318,2.41419},{6,324,2.43558},{6,330,2.29213},{6,336,2.46355},{6,342,2.58413},{6,348,2.47835},{6,354,2.17946},{6,360,2.34481},{6,366,2.8032},{6,372,2.52823},{6,378,2.79229},{6,384,2.58217},{6,390,2.6091},{6,396,2.42302},{6,402,2.73182},{6,408,2.45298},{6,414,3.1597},{6,420,2.66403},{6,426,2.39254},{6,432,2.87258},{6,438,2.61748},{6,444,2.70841},{6,450,2.55228},{6,456,2.54762},{6,462,2.49003},{6,468,2.94169},{6,474,2.45882},{6,480,2.79414},{6,486,2.28356},{6,492,2.92389},{6,498,2.56894},{6,504,3.34326},{6,510,3.09164},{6,516,2.74151},{6,522,2.9421},{6,528,2.71061},{6,534,2.60536},{6,540,2.64271},{6,546,2.64826},{6,552,2.71457},{6,558,2.46986},{6,564,2.48719},{6,570,2.28519},{6,576,2.20632},{6,582,2.30377},{6,588,2.68933},{6,594,2.37031},{6,600,2.25064},{6,606,3.12559},{6,612,2.91535},{6,618,2.82004},{6,624,3.13842},{6,630,2.9301},{6,636,2.72388},{6,642,2.83937},{6,648,3.1243},{6,654,2.64058},{6,660,2.81251},{6,666,2.98226},{8,0,0.647083},{8,6,0.448819},{8,12,0.441372},{8,18,0.633842},{8,24,0.537127},{8,30,0.776977},{8,36,0.682159},{8,42,1.00228},{8,48,1.03336},{8,54,0.86845},{8,60,0.798648},{8,66,1.21947},{8,72,1.06527},{8,78,1.13433},{8,84,1.19649},{8,90,1.33958},{8,96,1.16118},{8,102,1.35805},{8,108,1.38032},{8,114,1.31299},{8,120,1.04441},{8,126,1.41363},{8,132,1.21928},{8,138,1.34441},{8,144,1.38456},{8,150,1.18587},{8,156,1.2505},{8,162,1.31973},{8,168,1.27488},{8,174,1.24806},{8,180,1.30616},{8,186,1.31515},{8,192,1.26549},{8,198,1.35743},{8,204,1.45514},{8,210,1.41813},{8,216,1.23963},{8,222,1.37289},{8,228,1.35309},{8,234,1.57017},{8,240,1.3751},{8,246,1.67303},{8,252,1.64209},{8,258,1.58623},{8,264,1.81903},{8,270,1.43628},{8,276,1.49471},{8,282,1.64683},{8,288,1.65975},{8,294,1.51223},{8,300,1.61269},{8,306,1.59499},{8,312,1.81595},{8,318,1.38265},{8,324,1.51008},{8,330,1.51451},{8,336,1.55474},{8,342,1.6666},{8,348,1.61281},{8,354,1.34824},{8,360,1.30458},{8,366,1.65495},{8,372,1.65538},{8,378,1.61235},{8,384,1.56087},{8,390,1.49175},{8,396,1.65757},{8,402,1.56799},{8,408,1.63076},{8,414,1.72441},{8,420,1.74952},{8,426,1.29295},{8,432,1.54347},{8,438,1.57697},{8,444,1.56348},{8,450,1.54073},{8,456,1.58157},{8,462,1.39144},{8,468,1.7468},{8,474,1.69158},{8,480,1.73185},{8,486,1.41786},{8,492,1.77357},{8,498,1.66453},{8,504,1.99042},{8,510,1.95037},{8,516,1.71123},{8,522,1.65104},{8,528,1.83421},{8,534,1.64569},{8,540,1.48086},{8,546,1.63882},{8,552,1.74687},{8,558,1.53387},{8,564,1.57706},{8,570,1.50582},{8,576,1.31741},{8,582,1.47397},{8,588,1.59465},{8,594,1.47101},{8,600,1.60332},{8,606,1.81642},{8,612,1.81595},{8,618,1.66391},{8,624,1.87916},{8,630,1.88918},{8,636,1.71072},{8,642,1.79382},{8,648,1.89856},{8,654,1.71103},{8,660,1.60331},{8,666,1.87195},{10,0,0.35654},{10,6,0.336505},{10,12,0.229219},{10,18,0.37277},{10,24,0.391889},{10,30,0.390797},{10,36,0.456228},{10,42,0.626833},{10,48,0.540682},{10,54,0.381638},{10,60,0.347661},{10,66,0.623156},{10,72,0.509822},{10,78,0.513299},{10,84,0.503252},{10,90,0.616285},{10,96,0.559117},{10,102,0.582412},{10,108,0.580618},{10,114,0.516496},{10,120,0.544474},{10,126,0.653425},{10,132,0.489784},{10,138,0.539393},{10,144,0.58631},{10,150,0.604227},{10,156,0.654631},{10,162,0.557624},{10,168,0.563593},{10,174,0.544871},{10,180,0.51509},{10,186,0.694853},{10,192,0.549551},{10,198,0.591988},{10,204,0.662093},{10,210,0.53143},{10,216,0.493782},{10,222,0.687478},{10,228,0.602734},{10,234,0.728726},{10,240,0.539286},{10,246,0.767974},{10,252,0.729111},{10,258,0.725236},{10,264,0.723239},{10,270,0.603335},{10,276,0.661284},{10,282,0.72075},{10,288,0.741072},{10,294,0.571773},{10,300,0.624261},{10,306,0.716177},{10,312,0.733817},{10,318,0.678443},{10,324,0.643768},{10,330,0.649156},{10,336,0.708197},{10,342,0.82293},{10,348,0.708308},{10,354,0.605526},{10,360,0.604033},{10,366,0.828415},{10,372,0.787685},{10,378,0.731335},{10,384,0.787792},{10,390,0.755715},{10,396,0.727333},{10,402,0.824938},{10,408,0.716367},{10,414,0.787467},{10,420,0.774437},{10,426,0.636991},{10,432,0.759897},{10,438,0.690772},{10,444,0.679318},{10,450,0.572061},{10,456,0.712393},{10,462,0.671355},{10,468,0.770058},{10,474,0.638785},{10,480,0.743968},{10,486,0.701233},{10,492,0.84526},{10,498,0.695755},{10,504,0.875228},{10,510,0.849722},{10,516,0.803206},{10,522,0.749636},{10,528,0.780403},{10,534,0.694566},{10,540,0.580113},{10,546,0.650045},{10,552,0.631019},{10,558,0.705208},{10,564,0.607808},{10,570,0.596751},{10,576,0.542486},{10,582,0.594083},{10,588,0.739288},{10,594,0.62833},{10,600,0.569983},{10,606,0.677631},{10,612,0.749733},{10,618,0.686289},{10,624,0.852324},{10,630,0.918744},{10,636,0.769948},{10,642,0.679418},{10,648,0.755305},{10,654,0.751323},{10,660,0.704026},{10,666,0.837176}}`

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared at least a subset of your data.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Ok. I've just edited the question and put some points there.

Comment: you should first verify `TempDist` works for reasonable values of the parameters before trying to model fit.

Comment: @george2079 `TempDist`works. The problem, I think, is the time it takes to evaluate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so there are two parts to this problem. This first really boils down to how do I get `NonlinearModelFit` to stop throwing a tantrum? That can be handled pretty straightforwardly by requiring inputs to our model function `TempDist` to be numeric. The new function definition looks like:

```
TempDist[r_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, 
   Diff_?NumericQ, \[Alpha]_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(ro^2) Exp[-(ro^2 + r^2)/(4 Diff (t - ti))] BesselI[0, 
     ro r/(2 Diff (t - ti))] Exp[-\[Alpha]*z + (\[Alpha]^2)*
       Diff (t - ti)]*
    Erfc[(2 Diff \[Alpha] (t - ti) - z)/(Sqrt[
         4 Diff (t - ti)])]/(Diff (t - ti)), {ro, 0, a}, {ti, 0, t}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 10];
```

The second question requires a bit more consideration. Namely, does my model represent my data? If we take a look at the data you will notice that these data have some offset from the $\left(r,t\right)$ plane.

[image]

This is a problem because your function, as it is defined, can't have a nonzero value at $\left(r,t\right) = \left(0,0\right)$. Therefore, if you let the original model be defined as $f\left(r,t\right)$, construct a new model function $g\left(r,t\right)=f\left(r,t\right)+\Delta$, it is possible to fit an appropriate fit. Now, after some computation time, the call to `NonlinearModelFit` will yield a result:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  TempDist[r, 2, t, a, Diff, 0.023] + \[CapitalDelta], {{Diff, 
    0.5}, {a, .75}, {\[CapitalDelta], 34}}, {r, t}]
(*FittedModel[31.8606 +TempDist[r,2,t,2.90992,10.5851,0.023]]*)
```

Checking against the original data:

```
testdata = 
  Flatten[Table[{r, t, nlm[r, t]}, {r, Subdivide[0, 10, 10]}, {t, 
     Subdivide[0, 600, 10]}], 1];
Show[ListPlot3D[testdata], ListPointPlot3D[data]]
```

[image]

Comment: ! Thank you. Indeed, I've just realized that I forgot to subtract the baseline value (which you called $\Delta$) from the original data. I'm doing this right now and trying your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment.  @Marchi has shown you how to fix your function so that `NonlinearModelFit` will provide a solution.  What is recommended to do next is to examine the quality of the fit.

From the 3D plot above one sees that the assumption of constant variance assumed by `NonlinearModelFit` is just not true.  Either the variability increases with increases predicted value or increases with increases of `r`.  Another way to look at this is to construct estimates of the distribution of residuals for each value of `r`:

```
resids = nlm["FitResiduals"];
d0 = SmoothKernelDistribution[Pick[resids, data[[All, 1]], 0]];
d2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[Pick[resids, data[[All, 1]], 2]];
d4 = SmoothKernelDistribution[Pick[resids, data[[All, 1]], 4]];
d6 = SmoothKernelDistribution[Pick[resids, data[[All, 1]], 6]];
d8 = SmoothKernelDistribution[Pick[resids, data[[All, 1]], 8]];
d10 = SmoothKernelDistribution[Pick[resids, data[[All, 1]], 10]];
```

And now a plot of the estimated density functions for each value of `r`:

```
Plot[{PDF[d0, x], PDF[d2, x], PDF[d4, x], PDF[d6, x], PDF[d8, x], PDF[d10, x]},
 {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 2.6}},
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.007], Red}, {Thickness[0.007], Black}, {Thickness[0.007], Blue},
   {Thickness[0.007], Green}, {Thickness[0.007], Cyan}, {Thickness[0.007], Orange}},
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLegends -> {"r = 0", "r = 2", "r = 4", "r = 6", "r = 8", "r = 10"}]
```

[image: Residual distributions for each value of r]

One can see that estimate of constant variability is not justified and there is a considerable lack of fit:  none of the residual distributions seem to be centered around zero.